# How to store both the JSON object to mongodb, if two device hit the api at same time in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

In My project I have two hardware device. Each hitting my API with the JSON object every two minutes. If it hit different time, my controller stores both the JSON object mongodb.

BUT if both the device hit the API at same time, it stores 1st object to database for second one it is giving error.

If two device hit "pushSensorData" at same time that time am getting mongo error.

```js
pushSensorData: function(req, res) {

        receievedMessage = req.query;
        console.log('received message ', receievedMessage);
        MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function(err, db) {

            db.collection('sensor').find({ "sMacId": receievedMessage.MAC }).toArray(function(error, response) {
           ievedMessage.timestamp = new Date(receievedMessage.timestamp);
                receievedMessage["sensorMacId"] = receievedMessage.MAC.toString();
                if (receievedMessage.sensorMacId != null) {

                    receievedMessage["occupancy"] = parseInt(receievedMessage.OC);
                    receievedMessage["ambientLight"] = parseInt(receievedMessage.ALS);
                    receievedMessage["power"] = parseInt(receievedMessage.POW);
                    receievedMessage["timestamp"] = receievedMessage.timestamp;



                    if (isNaN(receievedMessage.occupancy))
                        receievedMessage["occupancy"] = 0;

                    if (isNaN(receievedMessage.ambientLight))
                        receievedMessage["ambientLight"] = 0;


                    if (isNaN(receievedMessage.power))
                        receievedMessage["power"] = 0;


                    delete receievedMessage.MAC;
                    delete receievedMessage.OC;
                    delete receievedMessage.ALS;
                    delete receievedMessage.POW;
                    insertDocument(db, function() {
                        db.close();
                    });

                } else {
                    db.close();
                }
            })


        });

        var insertDocument = function(db, callback) {
            db.collection('sensordata').insertMany([receievedMessage], function(err, response) {
                console.log("Inserted", response);
            });
        };

    },

};
```

this is the error am getting 
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
0|app      |     at /home/sp_mean/smartpower/api/controllers/SensorMessageController.js:63:71
0|app      |     at handleCallback (/home/sp_mean/smartpower/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:95:56)
0|app      |     at /home/sp_mean/smartpower/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:852:16
0|app      |     at handleCallback (/home/sp_mean/smartpower/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:171:5)
0|app      |     at setCursorNotified (/home/sp_mean/smartpower/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:516:3)
0|app      |     at /home/sp_mean/smartpower/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:591:16
0|app      |     at queryCallback (/home/sp_mean/smartpower/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:232:18)
0|app      |     at /home/sp_mean/smartpower/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:455:18
0|app      |     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
0|app      |     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
PM2        | App [app] with id [0] and pid [38409], exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:app id:0

Comment: hard to know for sure, but perhaps you need to use sessions?

Comment: i am pretty sure its due to you closing the mongo connection in the first request while the second request tries to hit the db. Try to just connect once on server start and leave it open.

Comment: It show *what* error?

Comment: @Paul, Can u tell how to sessions.

Answer (score 0):

if we look closely in your code, we can see that you're closing the database connection after the operation using `db.close();`
So, that throws an error in the second request execution, either you omit to close the database (it isn't a big deal actually), the process existing will handle this for you either way or use sessions to separate requests.

Comment: How to use sessions can u suggest me?

Comment: Can u tell how to sessions.